# C - Array value disappearing while setting the last at NULL

Tags: c, malloc, environment-variables

I'm having a little problem with a (pretty big) c program and figured out that the problem does not come from my program itself but the way I create my array, I think.

My problem is the following, I need to create an array who's identical to the one containing environment variables (`extern char **environ`) and then add another value at the end.

Here is a code that I've done to check if the `environ` is well copied or not:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_length(char **arr)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (arr[i])
        i++;
    return (i);
}

int main(void)
{
    extern char **environ;
    char **env;
    int err;
    int x;

    err = 0;
    x = 0;
    env = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * ft_length(environ) + 2);
    while (environ[x])
    {
    //  printf("%s\n", environ[x]);
        env[x] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(environ[x]) + 1);
        bzero(env[x], strlen(environ[x]));
        strncpy(env[x], environ[x], strlen(environ[x]));
    //  printf("%s\n", env[x]);
        x++;
    }
    env[x] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    env[x] = "ccc\0";
    env[++x] = NULL;
    x = 0;
    while (environ[x])
    {
        if (strcmp(environ[x], env[x]) != 0)
        {
            err++;
            printf("error on env[%d]\n", x);
            printf("environ[%d] : |%s|\n", x, environ[x]);
            printf("env[%d] : |%s|\n", x, env[x]);
            printf("----------------\n");
        }
        x++;
    }
    while (env[x])
    {
        if (strcmp(env[x], "ccc") != 0)
        {
            err++;
            printf("env[%d] contain |%s| instead of |ccc|\n", x, env[x]);
        }
        x++;
    }
    printf("done with %d error(s)\n", err);
    return (1);
}
```

When I run this code on Mac OSX, `env[0]` is empty at the end, and that happen when I set the last array value to `NULL` (`env[++x] = NULL`).  But, well, I need this one to be `NULL` if I want to print my array without segfault.

So, first I wanted to know if my code is wrong somewhere?

I tried to run this code on my Linux computer (Ubuntu 16.04) too and it seems there is no problem.

Comment: `A * B + C` is parsed as `(A * B) + C`. `sizeof(char*) * ft_length(environ) + 2` makes no sense.

Comment: `env[x] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    env[x] = "ccc\0";` leaks memory. It doesn't do what you think it does, and if it *did*, it'd be undefined behavior for out-of-bounds access.

Comment: @melpomene Oh you're right ! I'll fix it and try again as soon as possible.

Comment: @EOF I'll try to figure out why it does not what I think and fix it, thanks for the advice !

Comment: Although not the solution to the problem, I just wanted to point out that you should just do `strcpy(env[x], environ[x])` instead of doing the `bzero` and the `strncpy` (with the extra call to `strlen`).  The `sizeof(char) * strlen(environ[x]) + 1` also suffers from the `A * B + C` problem.

Comment: You never need to explicitly add a NUL to a string literal (unless you want 2 NULs).

Comment: `strncpy(env[x], environ[x], strlen(environ[x]));` This is called *cargo cult programming*. You are using `strncpy` because `strcpy` is "unsafe", right?

Comment: @n.m. I always use strcpy but wanted to check if it was the same with strncpy.
I know that strcpy is "unsafe" but don't know much about it so I still use it, I should document myself on this !

Comment: `strncpy` is unsafe when you pass exactly the length of the string you are copying, since it will *not* copy the NUL terminator (check the warning in the manpage).  I'm guessing the `bzero` was trying to account for this, but it does not since it only zeros the bytes before the NUL...  Your copied strings are potentially not terminated!

Comment: Actually, it's not clear why you can't just copy the pointers to the strings instead of copying the strings themselves, but if you really want to copy the strings, you should use `strdup` (if it's available).

Comment: Production code should check the return value from `malloc` too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
malloc(sizeof(char*) * ft_length(environ) + 2)
```

If you need two additional elements in the array, that'd be

```
malloc(sizeof(char*) * (ft_length(environ) + 2));
```

Or use `calloc`:

```
calloc (ft_length(environ) + 2, sizeof(char*));
```

In addition

```
env[x] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
env[x] = "ccc\0";
```

is another pitfall everybody seems to fall in. You assign a pointer value to `env[x]`, then immediately regret and assign another pointer value to it, forgetting the first one, creating a memory leak in process, and making your `env` impossible to `free` as the new string is not pointing to a dynamically allocated memory. This is particularly baffling as you seem to correctly (even if with much redundancy) copy a string a few lines earlier.

```
env[x] = malloc(4); // sizeof(char) is always one; casting not needed
                    // also see below
strcpy (env[x], "ccc"); // of course no `\0` is needed
```

Since you have code that dynamically allocates a copy of a string in two places, you may want to make this code into a function, or perhaps use an existing (albeit non-standard) function `strdup`. This is particularly important because there's no good way to copy a string literal otherwise.

```
env[x] = malloc(4); 
strcpy (env[x], "ccc");
```

Assumes the length. What if the literal will change?

```
env[x] = malloc(strlen("ccc")+1);                           
strcpy (env[x], "ccc");
```

What if someone changes one literal and forgets the other?

```
const char ccc[] = "ccc";
env[x] = malloc(sizeof(ccc));
strcpy (env[x], ccc);
```

This works but you have an extra line that declares a variable. This doesn't sound like much but why?

```
env[x] = strdup("ccc");
```

Looks better, maintains better.

If you write your own `strdup` don't do this

```
out = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(in) + 1);
bzero(out, strlen(in));
strncpy(out, in, strlen(in));
```

but rather

```
out = malloc(strlen(in) + 1);
strcpy(out, in);
```

`bzero` is redundant because it will zero out exactly the bytes that `strcpy` will overwrite with non-zero values at the next line. The `strncpy` + `strlen`  combo is **plain wrong** as it doesn't null-terminate the destination string. `strncpy(out, in, strlen(in)+1)` would be correct but redundant, as it does exactly the same thing as plain `strcpy(out, in)`.

Comment: The length of the string literal shouldn't be assumed in the call to `malloc`.  Use `strdup`, or implement your own `strdup`, and use it consistently!

Comment: @pat you beat me to it

Comment: I think you meant `malloc(strlen("ccc")+1)`, not `malloc("ccc")`.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks a lot for all those advices !